# kstrtol causing looping within class attribute

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have a simple kernel module which creates a sysfs node under /sys/class and adds a test attribute to the class. The test attribute has a store function which just uses kstrtol to convert a number residing in a character array to a long. It seems to work well; however, the function seems to get stuck in an infinite loop. I am extremely confused as to why. Anyone have any ideas?

```
static ssize_t test_store(struct class *c,
    struct class_attribute *attr,
    const char *buf,
    size_t count)
{
    int ret;
    long test;

    char testbuf[10] = "10\0";

    ret = kstrtol(testbuf, 10, &test);

    printk("Read test number%d", test);

    if (ret)
        return ret;

    return 0;
}

static CLASS_ATTR_WO(test);
```

Terminal output:

```
 echo 10 > /sys/class/vehicle_control/test
[   57.633697] Creating vehicle_control sysfs node
[   60.270140] Read test number10
[   60.273221] Read test number10
[   60.279476] Read test number10
[   60.281071] Read test number10
[   60.284113] Read test number10
[   60.289285] Read test number10
[   60.290879] Read test number10
[   60.293921] Read test number10
[   60.299085] Read test number10
[   60.300678] Read test number10
[   60.303720] Read test number10
[   60.308967] Read test number10
[   60.310560] Read test number10
[   60.313601] Read test number10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt):

> store() should return the number of bytes used from the buffer. If the
> entire buffer has been used, just return the count argument.

So in your case you may write `return count;`.